# Testing DB connection string on a server machine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, windows-server-2008, connection-string

Do you guys have any idea if there is anyway to test a connection string(if it is working or not) for a deployed .NET MVC app on a server machine without having VisualStudio and the code for the project?

Answer (score 0):

Use rest api tester
Example: For Google Chrome:postman rest client